# How to convert dates in format Jan 01-21 to YYYY-MM-DD in R?

Tags: r

I am working with data from excel to R. All of the other spreadsheets I imported returned in R as numbers from `1899-12-30`, and I was able to convert those to the format I need using `as.Date()`. This file uses Jan DD-YY format, and I can't figure out how to convert it in R. Everything I have tried has returned NA values. Any ideas to help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `mdy` function from `lubridate` package:

```
library(lubridate)

date <- "Jan 01-21"
mdy(date)
```

output:

```
> mdy(date)
[1] "2021-01-01"
```

---

Or another option is `parse_date`

```
library(parsedate)
parse_date(date)
[1] "2021-01-21 UTC"
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean this?

```
> as.Date("Jan 01-21", format = "%b %d-%y")
[1] "2021-01-01"
```